# Father's first name between the applicant's first and last name in Kuwait Visa, is it normal?

Tags: visas, e-visas, kuwait

My friend has received his E-visa to go to Kuwait. In the E-visa, his name is written like this:

> His first name + his father's first name +  His last name.

As an example, suppose my friends name is "Jack Williamson' and his father's first name is "Jim". So his name is written in Kuwait E-visa as "Jack Jim Williamson".

Is this normal? Is that the way they write names in visas?